# Laravel : How to Update multiple Select option with select2.js

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, eloquent

I want to update my database but it send repeated  value in option field .

[image]

Here is my Html code :

```
<select name="size_id[]" multiple="multiple" style="margin-bottom:15px;"
        class="form-control select_multiple">
  @foreach($sizes as $skey=>$sitem)
        @foreach ($product->Sizes as $pkey=>$psize)
                <option value="{{$sitem->id }}"}} @if($sitem->id == $psize->id)selected="selected"@endif>
                    {{ $sitem->name}}+{{$skey}}
                </option>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Product Model:

```
 public function Sizes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class,'product_sizes');
    }
```

Size Model :

```
public function Products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'size_products','product_id','size_id');
}
```

Comment: `$sitem->id` will form the keys for select2, and because you use it inside the inner loop, its going to be repeated.

Comment: how to solve it

Comment: `@if($sitem->id == $psize->id)` why did you do this?

Comment: just for add a tag

Answer (score 5):

You can use Collections [containsStrict](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-containsstrict) to check if it has the item's id equal to the any of the sizes like this:

```
<select name="size_id[]" multiple="multiple" style="margin-bottom:15px;"
                                            class="form-control select_multiple">
@foreach($sizes as $skey=>$sitem)                                   
        <option value="{{$sitem->id }}"}} @if($product->Sizes->containsStrict('id', $item->id)) selected="selected" @endif>
        {{ $sitem->name }}+{{ $skey }}
    </option>
 @endforeach                                       
</select>
```